# I have a data inside the state in T and Z format and React input accepts in the HH:MM ss format so how to convert

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass the data to the form input but that is not accepting the TZ format so how can I convert it to the format which accepts the valid format

```js
<input
     className="form-control"
     type="datetime-local"
     name="start"
     id="start"
     placeholder="Start Date"
     onChange={this.onChange}
     value={this.state.editData.start || ''} //HERE I want pass
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to do that. So install moment, import it and use it like that:

```
<input
  className="form-control"
  type="datetime-local"
  name="start"
  id="start"
  placeholder="Start Date"
  onChange={this.onChange}
  value={moment(this.state.editData.start).format('hh:mm ss') || ''}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `moment.js` to format your date to accepted format .

```
<input className="form-control" 
type="datetime-local" 
name="start" 
id="start" 
placeholder="Start Date" 
onChange={this.onChange} 
value={this.state.editData.start?moment(this.srate.editData.start,"initial format like yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").format("required format like HH:mm A"): ''} 
/>
```

Also on `onChange` method save date in "initial format"